# How to configure SSL in Apache on local server in Linux?

Tags: linux, apache, ssl

Can any one send me the good link for configuration of SSL in Apache on local server.I searched on google but did not find the any complete method for local apache server.
Thanks

Comment: Really? Couldn't find ANYTHING on how to configure Apache? http://httpd.apache.org should be your FIRST stop for anything apache related.

Comment: There is no method for configuration of SSL

Answer (score 2):

Install openssl:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Create directory to save certificate:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl

sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl/certs

sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl/private

enable ssl module in apache

sudo a2enmod ssl
```

go to `cd /etc/apache2/ssl/private`

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout website_ssl.key -out website_ssl.csr -sha256
```

u will get two files .csr and .key

download your ssl by uploading your  csr to your ssl provider and once certificate issued download the files to

```
cd /etc/apache2/ssl/certs
```

open `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`

```
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.in/certs/
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.in/
 SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.in/certs/
```

add .key .csr and gb_bundle.csr in apache2

to enable

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl.conf

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant setting up `apache` for using HTTPS, you may follow the next tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps

Comment: i saw this tutorial but i need a method for localhost.

Comment: There is no difference which host do you use

Answer (score 0):

**I think that's the [tutorial you need](https://www.futurefundamentals.com/how-to-configure-ssl-on-localhost-ubuntu-apache2/)**

**Steps**:

> sudo a2enmod ssl
>
> sudo service apache2 restart
>
> sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout
> /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
>
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

- **Replace the content with the content from the Tutorial.**
- Basicly for a new website, just copy the file and change the name of the folder and host

> sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

It worked for me